# Adding Items To List In Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I'm trying to implement a submit button to where the user inputs their information in 3 textboxes and when they click on the submit button, the information gets stored into a list which allows me to add it to an object that I have created.

I have tried creating a temporary list, the first index seems to display fine, but I'm really struggling to understand how to add onto the list and how to make it so when they click on 'submit' again, it stores in the next index.

Every time I click on submit, it contentiously stores in the first index.

```
private Fleet boatOne;
private Fleet boatTwo;
private Fleet boatThree;
private Fleet boatFour;
```

```
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> tempTextBox = new List<string>();
    tempTextBox.Add(BoatNameTextBox.Text);
    tempTextBox.Add(BoatNameTextBox.Text);

    string licenseVariable = BoatLicenseTextBox.Text;
    string intVariable = MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;

    boatOne = new Fleet(tempTextBox[0], licenseVariable, intVariable);
    BoatNameTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatName();
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatLicense();
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetmaximumLoad();

    boatTwo = new Fleet(tempTextBox[1], licenseVariable, intVariable);
    BoatNameTextBox.Text = boatTwo.GetboatName();
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = boatTwo.GetboatLicense();
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = boatTwo.GetmaximumLoad();

    BoatNameTextBox.Text = "";
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "";
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "";
```

Also, when I click on the submit button, not only do I want it storing the information into an object, but I want the object to display properly into my DataGridView.

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Boat Name");
dt2.Columns.Add("License Number");
dt2.Columns.Add("Maximum Load");

dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatOne.GetboatName(), boatOne.GetboatLicense(), boatOne.GetmaximumLoad() });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatTwo.GetboatName(), boatTwo.GetboatLicense(), boatTwo.GetmaximumLoad() });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatThree });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatFour });
BoatDataGridView.DataSource = dt2;
BoatDataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
BoatDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;

BoatDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
BoatDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

FishDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
FishDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: Perplexed, you create two fleet objects with identical information. Then you set the content of the first fleet object to some textboxes, then you _replace_ the textboxes content with the information from the second fleet (identical to the first one) finally you clear everything from the textboxes. Sorry but it is not clear what you  are really trying to do

Comment: Sorry, my code looks like complete spaghetti, what I want is really simple, the user inputs their information, clicks on submit button and the information they've inputted, gets stored into a growing list, how I do that, I don't know.

I wanted the textboxes to clear after I click on submit, which helps visually show that the users input has been stored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
List<Fleet> boatList = new List<Fleet>();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

private Fleet currentBoat;
private int boats = 0;
```

```
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string licenseVariable = BoatLicenseTextBox.Text;
    string intVariable = MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;

    if (BoatNameTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Name", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        boatList.Add(new Fleet(BoatNameTextBox.Text, licenseVariable, 
        intVariable));
        currentBoat = boatList[boats];
        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { currentBoat.GetboatName(), 
        currentBoat.GetboatLicense(), currentBoat.GetmaximumLoad() });             
    }

    BoatNameTextBox.Text = "";
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "";
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "";
    boats++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with nearly no code (written by you I mean) at all:

- right click your project in solution explorer
- add a new item
- make it a DataSet, give it a suitable name
- on the design surface for the dataset right click and choose Add New.. DataTable
- name it Fleet (personally I would name it Boat but..)
- right click it and add columns for name, license number etc
- save the set
- open the forms designer
- show the Data sources window (view menu >> other windows >> data sources)
- expand the datset node
- drag the Fleet node into the forms designer
- expand the fleet node
- drag all the children of it to the forms designer too

You now have text boxes and a grid, data bound to the same dataset. You also have a menu bar type thing with an add button and some navigators etc

Run the program. You can either type in the grid cells or the text boxes. You can use the nav buttons or click different rows in the grid to change the current row

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add elements to a list and then update a DataGridView, then you don't need the individual Fleet elements. Just one List(Of Fleet)

```
private List<Fleet> myBoats = new List<Fleet>();

....
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fleet boat = new Fleet(BoatNameTextBox.Text, BoatLicenseTextBox.Text, MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;);
    myBoats.Add(boat);    
    BoatDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    BoatDataGridView.DataSource = myBoats;

    BoatNameTextBox.Text = "";
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "";
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

However, you could use a simplified approach if you bind your DataGridView to a BindingList instead of a simple List. The BindingList object has the ability to automatically refresh the binded object

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BoatDataGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<Fleet>();
}
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fleet boat = new Fleet(BoatNameTextBox.Text, BoatLicenseTextBox.Text, MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;);
    BindingList<Fleet> bs = BoatDataGridView.DataSource as BindingList<Fleet>;
    bs.Add(boat);
    BoatNameTextBox.Text = "";
    BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "";
    MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: How would I access the indexes to Boat1 and it's name/maximum weight etc, and display them into a DataGrid? (sorry for the stupid questions)

Comment: @unboundphantom you don't "access the boats and put them in a grid" - you have a grid, you bind it to a BindingList, you put the boats in the list and the they will automatically appear in the grid (google data binding)

Comment: A List or a BindingList could be used like it was an array. You have already done it when you had retrieved the boatname. Just use bs[0] to get the first Fleet object

Comment: @Steve how do you add Columns to a binding list? I'm getting the error `{"No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first."}`

Comment: [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8) with an example to look at